# Detection of inhomogeneous illuminated object

Tags: image-processing

Here is an `image` with an inhomogeneous illuminated disk shaped object in the center.

[image]

It is illuminated from left. Therefore on the left it is brighter and at right it is dark.

By eye one can guess where the edges of the object are.

**How would you detect this oject's center and radius?**

What I tried is not very successfull:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKFDd.png"];

binimg = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, 0.45], 70]
```

[image]

```
pts = Values@ComponentMeasurements[binImg, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]

{{{80.99, 106.566}, 18.2557}}

radius = pts[[1, 2]]

18.2557

center = pts[[1, 1]]

{80.99, 106.566}

Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Point[center]}], Graphics[{Red, Circle[center, r]}]]
```

[image]

The center is too far left and the radius is too large.

Manually I would draw the following circle:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you can get a perfectly unbiased estimate of the center you're interested in. If you look at a 3d plot of the image data, it's clear that the "disk" isn't symmetric, and probably overexposed on the light side:

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKFDd.png"], 
  "Grayscale"]
ListPlot3D[ImageData[img], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I think the best (and simplest) thing to do would be to use a linear filter kernel with a similar shape, i.e. a Gaussian derivative kernel:

```
Image[Rescale@GaussianMatrix[25, {0, 1}]]
```

[image]

I would expect that filtering the image with a filter kernel that looks like this should give the highest value where the "bright sides" and the "dark sides" of the filter kernel and the object match:

```
match = ImageAdjust@ColorNegate@GaussianFilter[img, 25, {0, 1}]
```

[image]

the bright peak looks close to the position you're interested in:

```
center = PixelValuePositions[match, "Max"][[1]]
HighlightImage[img, Circle[center, 25]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you very much for the answer.